# Variable is not taking in value?

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel VBA, I declared two variables (`RowNumberPlus1` and `RowNumber`) and created a `do while loop` as well as `if, else` statements nested inside.
I'm trying to iterate by using `RowNumberPlus1 = RowNumber + 1` because I wanted to keep the value of `RowNumber` outside of that particular `ElseIf` statement.
However, my `RowNumberPlus1` is not taking in that expression and stays as 0, the value I initiated it with.

The code looks like this:

```
Sub FormatBreakerSettingsData()

'Define variables for the Breaker Settings Fields
Dim DevName As Long
Dim DevName2 As Long
Dim RowNumber As Long
Dim RowNumberPlus1 As Long

'Define other variables
Dim NumOfBkrRows As Long
Dim NumOfBkrs As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim AColValue As String



'Set other variables appropriately
RowNumber = 6
NumOfBkrRows = 0
NumOfBkrs = 0
i = 0
j = 0
AColValue = Range("A6").Value

'Find number of breakers
Do While j <> 1
    If AColValue = "LV Fuses" Then 'Fuse info starts with a row labelled "LV Fuses" in Col A
    j = 1
    Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "HV/MV with Trip-Unit" Then '
    j = 1
    Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "HV/MV without Trip-Unit" Then '
    j = 1
    Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "Relays" Then '
    j = 1
    Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "MCP" Then '
    j = 1
    Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "MOL" Then '
    j = 1
    Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "HV Fuses" Then '
    j = 1
    Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "Switches" Then '
    j = 1
    Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "" Then '
        RowNumberPlus1 = RowNumber + 1
        End If
        AColValue = Range("A" & RowNumberPlus1)
        If AColValue = "" Then
            RowNumberPlus1 = RowNumberPlus1 + 1
            AColValue = Range("A" & RowNumberPlus1)
            End If
            If AColValue = "" Then
                j = 1
                End If
                Exit Do


    NumOfBkrRows = NumOfBkrRows + 1
    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
    AColValue = Range("A" & RowNumber)
Loop
NumOfBkrs = NumOfBkrRows / 4
```

Comment: To get usefuly answers in StackOverflow, please always post the code you're talking about, otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't realize I posted the problem without my code. @MarkusAppel

Comment: Nothing in your code changes the value of `RowNumber`.

Comment: @SJR There is other code that changes the value of RowNumber and when I debug it, it's working fine. The problem I'm having is RowNumberPlus1 = RowNumber + 1. When I hover over RowNumberPlus1, the value of that variable comes out to 0 even though it should be 1 as per the expression on the left (RowNumber + 1)

Comment: Does this not error `Dim RowNumberPlus1 = 0`? You can't declare and set a value like that. Without seeing the rest of your code hard to say. Have you stepped through to see what's going on?

Comment: @SJR I've edited my post to include the full code for clarity

Comment: `blahblah = RowNumberPlus1 + RowNumber` -- what is `blahblah`? It would help if you provide a [mcve] (with an emphasis on minimal). I am not able to actually run your code. As far as hovering goes -- you might be seeing the value of the variable *before* the expression is evaluated, not after. It is easy to get confused by that point when in debug mode.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yup, I've cleaned it up. The blahblah was just testing to see if another variable would work and take in the expression's outcome value. I've deleted it.

Comment: You are best placed to work out what's going wrong using breakpoints, stepping through and the locals window. It's not really obvious (to me at least).

Comment: It seems odd that `Exit Do` appears *after* `End If`. I think that you are misled by your own inconsistent indentation and are always exiting the loop before `RowNumber = RowNumber + 1` is ever encountered.

Comment: @JohnColeman - well spotted, I think you're right. You've actually got this line `If AColValue = "" Then` three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unconditional `Exit Do` towards the bottom of the loop (note that it appears *after* the final `End If`). That is causing the loop to terminate before the line `RowNumber = RowNumber + 1` is ever encountered.

There are quite possibly other bugs in your code. If so, fixing the indentation would be a good place to start the needed debugging. I suspect that the conditionals are not actually nested inside each other in the way that you might think. If you want to fix it automatically, the built-in VBA editor doesn't have an autoindent feature, but the [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) add-in does